# How to hide the '.com' text on buttons from WooCommerce product pages

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using affiliate products on woocommerce the affiliate URLs have a shortcode at the backend (Buy at %Domain%). which displays automatically on every product based on domain.com so I attempted to hide the '.com' text due to its buggy appearance, which was causing the page to load slowly. I employed CSS and a small script, which functioned perfectly until yesterday. However, at present, the text over the button is empty.

I don't know where I went wrong here.

```
  .gspb_id-gsbp-f2fd5af a {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .gspb_id-gsbp-f2fd5af a.completed {
    visibility: visible;
  }


<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const linkEls = document.querySelectorAll(".gspb_id-gsbp-f2fd5af a");
    linkEls.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.innerHTML.includes(" at ")) {
el.innerHTML=  el.innerHTML.replaceAll("number_format_thousands_sep",",").replaceAll("number_format_decimal_point",".");

        let arr = el.innerHTML.split(" at ");
        arr[0] = arr[0].replace(/\..+/, "").replace(/,/g, "");
        arr[1] = arr[1].replace(/\.com/, "");
        el.innerHTML = arr.join(" at ");
        el.classList.add("completed");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

---

this is the second version of code which I tried and failed as it didn't workout

```
<style>
  .gspb_id-gsbp-f2fd5af a {
    visibility: visible; /* Set default visibility to visible */
  }
  .gspb_id-gsbp-f2fd5af a.hide-text {
    visibility: hidden; /* Hide the text when the class is applied */
  }
</style>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const linkEls = document.querySelectorAll(".gspb_id-gsbp-f2fd5af a");
    linkEls.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.innerHTML.includes(" at ")) {
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replaceAll("number_format_thousands_sep", ",").replaceAll("number_format_decimal_point", ".");
        let arr = el.innerHTML.split(" at ");
        arr[0] = arr[0].replace(/\..+/, "").replace(/,/g, "");
        arr[1] = arr[1].replace(/\.com/g, "");
        el.innerHTML = arr.join(" at ");
        el.classList.add("hide-text"); // Apply the class to hide the text
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lol, I found it! Okay, in the version below, instead of a URL link, I have used text with the replace method. Voila, it works perfectly now.

The thing is, the code below works even if you're using shortcodes on your site, and yes, I removed the price strings.

If someone wants to use the code below, **replace the CSS classes**, and it can work for you.

```
<style>
  a.product_type_external.wp-element-button {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  a.product_type_external.wp-element-button.completed {
    visibility: visible;
  }
</style>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const linkEls = document.querySelectorAll("a.product_type_external.wp-element-button");
    linkEls.forEach((el) => {
      if (el.innerHTML.includes(".com")) {
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/\.com/, "");
        el.classList.add("completed");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```